# Preserve the order by ids in postgresql with DISTINCT

Tags: postgresql, group-by, distinct

I have a query, which returns a simple list of numbers:

```sql
SELECT unnest(c) FROM t ORDER BY f LIMIT 10;
```

And it goes like

```
1
1
3
4
2
3
5
1
5
6
3
2
```

I want to keep the result unique, but also preserve order:

```
1
3
2
4
5
6
```

```sql
select distinct(id) from (select ...) as c;
```

does not work, beacuse it uses `HashAggregate`, which breaks order (and processes all rows to return just 10?). I tried `GROUP BY`, it also uses `HashAggregate` the whole table(?) and then sort and return 10 required rows.

Is it possible to do it effectively on DB size? Or should I just read rows from my first query in my application and do the stream filtering?

Comment: you mean this? `SELECT DISTINCT unnest(c) FROM t ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 10;`

Comment: Note that `distinct` is not a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: @JimJones No, `ORDER BY 1` sorts by `c`. I need to sort by the initial order they appearance

Comment: @dmzkrsk I see. So use `UNNEST .. WITH ORDINALITY ...` ;)

Answer (score 1):

`with ordinality` is your friend to preserve the order.

```sql
select val 
from unnest('{1,1,3,4,2,3,5,1,5,6,3,2}'::int[]) with ordinality t(val, ord)
group by val
order by min(ord); -- the first time that this item appeared
```

| val |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 2 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

Or it may make sense to define this function:

```sql
create function arr_unique(arr anyarray) 
returns anyarray language sql immutable as
$$
select array_agg(val order by ord)
from
(
 select val, min(ord) ord 
 from unnest(arr) with ordinality t(val, ord)
 group by val
) t;
$$;
```

Comment: `group by` will use `HashAggregate` the whole table. That's what I try to avoid.

Comment: `select id, n from (SELECT ids FROM t ORDER BY f) AS c, unnest(c.ids) with ordinality as u(id, n);` gives me `(1,1), (1,1), (3,2), (4,1)`. `n` starts with `1` for each `row`, so `group by` does not work properly

Comment: ` with ordinality` + `group by` works for single `unnest`, I suppose. I have multiple rows, that I `unnest`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select elem
from (
  select 
  elem, elem_no, row_no, row_number() over (partition by elem order by row_no) as occurence_no
  from (
     select elem, elem_no, row_number() over () as row_no from t, unnest(c) WITH ORDINALITY a(elem, elem_no)
  ) A 
) B 
where occurence_no = 1
order by row_no
```

Comment: It also `HashAggregate`s the whole table to find unique values